# Generate HTML 4 Semantics in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While creating MVC 3 Razor, application we had selected `Generate HTML5 Semantics`. We realize that web app. has to be supported on `IE8`, as well.

How do I disable `HTML 5` semantic generation, in existing MVC-3 project.

Thanks !

Comment: IE8 can support semantic markup if you include Modernizr.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a setting in Visual Studio which allows you to change the DOCTYPE to HTML 4.01. Then you should of course replace all HTML5 tags in your markup:

[image]

Also if you include `modernizr`, IE8 can support semantic markup. Javascript will be used to achieve the same effects.